# Python utcfromtimestamp and fromtimestamp output same value?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, datetime, django-1.9

I have a Python+Django app which stores everything in UTC, and has `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'` and `USE_TZ = True` in the settings. When converting a POSIX timestamp I get the same output from both flavors of `fromtimestamp`:

```
start_seconds = 1461798000000 / 1000.0

start = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(start_seconds)
print('With utc: %s' % start)
>>>> With utc: 2016-04-27 23:00:00

start2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(start_seconds)
print('Without utc: %s' % start2)
>>>> Without utc: 2016-04-27 23:00:00
```

Why would this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `fromtimestamp()` and `ucfromtimestamp()` return the same value then it means the local time zone has a zero utc offset at the given time. Django sets your local timezone (`TZ` envvar), to reflect the `TIME_ZONE` setting that is UTC in your case and (obviously) the utc offset is zero in UTC.

To get a timezone-aware datetime object that corresponds to a given POSIX timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc) + timedelta(seconds=start_seconds)
```

To convert Unix time:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(start_seconds, pytz.utc)
```

The values may differ in edge cases.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and also for the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code gives me the expected results, which are naive datetimes in their offset to their respective timezones. According to epochconverter the timestamp you provided is 2016-04-27 23:00:00 UTC

```
In[23]: import datetime
In[24]: start_seconds = 1461798000000 / 1000.0
In[25]: start = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(start_seconds)
In[26]: print('With utc: %s' % start)
With utc: 2016-04-27 23:00:00  # Correct UTC time
In[27]: start2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(start_seconds)
In[28]: print('Without utc: %s' % start2)
Without utc: 2016-04-27 19:00:00  # Correct EDT time (my local timezone)
```